# IntelliJ - How do I get it to warn me about implicit access of static members?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, static, warnings

How do I configure IntelliJ to give me a warning whenever I try to access a static member of the class without typing the class name before it?

```
public class Car
{
    static int lastIDgiven = 0
    private int id;
    public Car()
    {
        id = lastIDgiven;
        incrementLastID();
    }
    static void incrementLastID()
    {
        lastIDgiven ++;
    }
}
```

In this example, I would like IntelliJ to warn me about "id = lastIDgiven;", and suggest that I change it to "id = Car.lastIDgiven". Same with "incrementLastID()" - I want it to suggest "Car.incrementLastID()". And the same inside incrementLastID(), when I type "lastIDgiven++" (even though it's within a static method).

IntelliJ has so many settings, especially for inspection, but I couldn't find this specific one - only the "access static member via instance reference" inspection, which is relevant to stuff like "someCar.lastIDgiven".

I want IntelliJ to warn me about this particular behavior because it is not immediately clear that the field/method is static while calling it this way, and I like having the program warn me about confusing code.

So, is there a setting option for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, IntelliJ IDEA has an inspection for that, it's called **Unqualified static access**.

[image: Unqualified static access]

> Reports static method calls or field accesses that are not qualified
>   with the class name of the static method. This is legal if the static
>   method or field is in the same class as the call, but may be
>   confusing.